# Innodb: Operating system error number 1117 in a file operation

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1067

i installed apache and mysql 5.5 on windows 7 64 bit. it worked but today mysql can not start and windows give me this error "Can't start MySQL Error 1067" when i try to start mysql manually.
.
i see this lines in error log :

```
120616 16:35:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120616 16:35:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120616 16:35:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
120616 16:35:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120616 16:35:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 103.0M
120616 16:35:48 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120616 16:35:48 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120616 16:35:50  InnoDB: **Operating system error number 1117 in a file operation.**
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File name .\ib_logfile0
InnoDB: File operation call: 'Windows aio'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

what is problem and InnoDB: Operating system error number 1117 in a file operation.
?

what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find this [link](http://imknight.net/development/cant-start-mysql-error-1067/). i removed the ib_logfile0 or ib_logfile1 in the data folder and it works.